# Format "12345678" to "1234-5678"

Tags: c#, string, format

How to format a string of numbers "12345678" to "1234-5678".

```
string str = "12345678";

//I want to format it like below
res = "1234-5678";
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a pattern to it? I.e, do you want to always display a hyphen after the first four digits and before the last four? Will it allways be 8 characters? Please elaborate a little on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx):

```
string res = "12345678".Insert(4, "-");
```

The parameters are the index to insert into and the string to insert.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to format numbers, you can use [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method:

```
int test = 12345678;
string res = String.Format("{0:####-####}", test); // res == "1234-5678"
```

Comment: All suggestions are right. But I prefered String.Format(). Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

How I could understand your desirable format is: to insert a hyphen after first four symbols in the string. if so, then It is very simple:

res = str.Length > 4 ? string.Concat (str.Substring (0, 4), "-", str.Substring (4)) : str;

If your format is other, please descride it in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .Substring like so:

```
string str1 = str.Substring(0,4);
string str2 = str.Substring(4,4);
string res = str1 + "-" + str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Visual Basic Code
It is not hard to convert on C#

```
    Dim str As String = "12345678"
    Dim num As Long = CLng(str)
    Dim strOut As String = Format(num, "####-####")
```